# Problem with Boost::Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Why this (copied from [boost site](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/hello-the-testing-world.html) ) gives me an error?! in VS 2010 Ultimate:

```
#include <boost\test\unit_test.hpp>

#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest


int add( int i, int j ) { return i+j; }

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( my_test )
{
    // seven ways to detect and report the same error:
    BOOST_CHECK( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );        // #1 continues on error

    BOOST_REQUIRE( add( 2,2 ) == 4 );      // #2 throws on error

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
      BOOST_ERROR( "Ouch..." );            // #3 continues on error

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 )
      BOOST_FAIL( "Ouch..." );             // #4 throws on error

    if( add( 2,2 ) != 4 ) throw "Ouch..."; // #5 throws on error

    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE( add( 2,2 ) == 4,  // #6 continues on error
                         "add(..) result: " << add( 2,2 ) );

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL( add( 2,2 ), 4 );   // #7 continues on error
}
```

**Error**

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::unit_test::test_suite * __cdecl init_unit_test_suite(int,char * * const)" (?init_unit_test_suite@@YAPAVtest_suite@unit_test@boost@@HQAPAD@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try defining `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` before you include the header.

Comment: now I'm getting: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Comment: @There: Read the [documentation](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation.html). Especially the part about auto-linking. You may have to link the library manually. I cannot help you more than that at the moment.

Comment: This one of those annoying things I forget from time to time. Grrr! Arggggh!